# How to understand Demartines theorem

Tags: probability

Demartines [theorem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E7B3755A2E4CDBA0341EC63A64BEC996?doi=10.1.1.71.5972&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (page 3) explain why norm of a random vector increases with dimension, whereas its variance remains constant:

*Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random vector with i.i.d. components: $X_i \sim \mathcal{F}$. Then,*
$$
\text{E} \left[ \|X\|_2  \right] = \sqrt{ad-b} + O \left( \frac{1}{d} \right)
$$
*and*
$$
\text{Var} \left( \| X \|_2 \right) = b + O \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \right)
$$
*where $a$ and $b$ are constants that do not depend on the dimension.*

The theorem proves that the expectation of the euclidean norm of random vectors increases as the square root of the dimension $d$, whereas its variance is constant and independent of the dimension. When the dimension is large, the variance of the norm is very small compared with its expected value.

My questions:

1. What does $O$ stands for?
2. Why does norm increases with the square root of dimension? How can we see that?
3. Why is variance constant? How can we see that?

Comment: This is a minor variant of the Central Limit Theorem, which asserts the standardized version of $||X||_2^2$ is asymptotically Normal. It requires that $X$ have finite variance.